# Métodos com parâmetro Dynamic C#

Tags: c#, classes, método

Preciso da ajuda dos senhores com na seguinte questão.

Tenho uma classe de acesso a dados que possui um método que recebe os parâmetros para executar uma stored procedure.

O problema é o seguinte, tenho vários objetos na aplicação e estou tentando criar uma classe que recebe um destes objetos e execute o método de adicionar parâmetros de acordo com o objeto recebido.

Segue código feito até agora:

Método da classe de acesso a dados que recebe os paramentros.

```
    public void AddParamentros(string parametro, dynamic valorParametro)
    {
        listaParamentrosSql.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = parametro, Value = valorParametro });
    }
```

Uso da classe de dados:

```
public class ManterDados
{
    AcessoDadosSql acessoDados = new AcessoDadosSql();

    public string manter(dynamic objeto, StoredProcedures procedure)
    {
        //Limpa parâmetros adicionados
        acessoDados.LimparParametros();
        // Adiciona os parametros 
        addParametrosSql addParam = new addParametrosSql(objeto);
        // Executa a SP
        string retorno = acessoDados.ExecutaSql(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, procedure);
        return retorno;
    }

}
```

Esta é classe que estou com problema:

```
public class addParametrosSql
{


    AcessoDadosSql acessoDados = new AcessoDadosSql();

    private void adicionarParametros(PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica)
    {

        acessoDados.AddParamentros("@Cnpj", pessoaJuridica.CNPJ);
        acessoDados.AddParamentros("@IE", pessoaJuridica.INSCRICAO_ESTADUAL);
        acessoDados.AddParamentros("@Suframa", pessoaJuridica.SUFRAMA);

    }
    private void adicionarParametros(PessoaFisica pessoaFisica)
    {

        acessoDados.AddParamentros("@Cpf", pessoaFisica.CPF);
        acessoDados.AddParamentros("@Nome", pessoaFisica.NOME);

    }
}
```

Qual o procedimento correto para a classe addParametrosSql executar o método adicionarParametros de acordo com o objeto passado como parâmetro?

Quando eu passo o parametro como Dynamic, mesmo sendo do tipo PessoaJuridica ou 
pessoaFisica ele não executa nem um método.

Tentei criar um construtor converter o parâmetro recebido para o tipo correto, mas não deu certo.

### **EDIT:**

Desta forma está funcionando, teria como melhorar este código?

```
    private void adicionarParamentros(object objeto)
    {
        acessoDados.LimparParametros();

        Type tipo = objeto.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propriedade in tipo.GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
             acessoDados.AddParamentros("@" + propriedade.Name, propriedade.GetValue(objeto, null));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinceramente, esta maneira vai te gerar mais retrabalho do que te ajudar.

Primeiro, eu deixaria sua classe `addParametrosSql` genérica. Aliás, o nome é horrível. Vou escolher um nome melhor, ok?

```
public class ParametrosSqlHelper<TClasse>
    where TClasse: class, new()
{
    AcessoDadosSql acessoDados = new AcessoDadosSql();
    private TClasse _objeto;

    private ParametrosSqlHelper() { } // Evita de ter construtor público vazio, se você for fazer com construtor mesmo.
    public ParametrosSqlHelper(TClasse objeto) // Acho que não precisa.
    {
        _objeto = objeto;
    }

    private void adicionarParametros(TClasse classe)
    {
        foreach (var propriedade in classe.GetType().GetProperties()) 
        {
            acessoDados.AddParamentros("@" + propriedade.Name, propriedade.GetValue(classe, null));
        }
    }
}
```

`ManterDados` ficaria assim:

```
public class ManterDados
{
    AcessoDadosSql acessoDados = new AcessoDadosSql();

    public string manter(object objeto, StoredProcedures procedure)
    {
        //Limpa parâmetros adicionados
        acessoDados.LimparParametros();
        // Adiciona os parametros 
        var addParam = new ParametrosSqlHelper<PessoaJuridica>(objeto);
        // Executa a SP
        string retorno = acessoDados.ExecutaSql(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, procedure); // Eu não entendi isso aqui.
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

`AddParametros` está com a grafia errada, e não sei se isso precisa existir mesmo, até porque não tem como definir a tipagem do parâmetro, mas fora a grafia está ok também.

```
public void AddParametros(string parametro, dynamic valorParametro)
{
    listaParamentrosSql.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = parametro, Value = valorParametro });
}
```

Comment: Cigano obrigado pela ajuda,  nesta parte  "var addParam = new ParametrosSqlHelper<PessoaJuridica>(objeto);" você esta passando o tipo PessoaJuridica, minha ideia era criar uma classe que eu passasse o parâmentro sem tipo e a classe que ficaria responsável por "saber" que tipo era esse e executar o método, seria viável isto?

Comment: Dá pra fazer não tipado também. Minha abordagem usando classe genérica (`TClasse`) é só uma sugestão.

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer não tipado. Vou ter que fazer uma alteração no DTO do projeto pois eu não estava deixando as classes da aplicação de acordo com os objetos do banco de dados, então no "foreach" dava erro de parâmetro. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: +1, muito bom, vou inclusive procurar aderir